# ABP.IO Show permissions based on features

Tags: permissions

I have an application that defines two features:

Feature A
Feature B

If Feature A is active for a tenant, then the user is allowed to see 'Screen A', and
if Feature B is active for a tenant, then the user is allowed to see 'Screen B'

Inside each screen, I control the actions the users can do defining some permissions (i.e Create | Update | Delete)

The problem is, every tenant can see and check any permissions in the permissions screen, I want to hide some permissions if the feature is disabled, this is:

If Feature A is disabled for a tenant, then that tenant cannot see nor assign the permissions for 'Screen A'

I tried checking the features in the PermissionDefinitionProviderImpl class, but it does not work because this class is just called once, not per request.

Please your comments.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in this article:
https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/5.3/UI/Angular/Permission-Management-Component-Replacement

The key point here is that you have to overwrite the default PermissionManagment component.

You can read more about replaceable components here:
https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/5.3/UI/Angular/Component-Replacement

The source code for the original ABP component is here:
https://github.com/abpframework/abp/tree/dev/npm/ng-packs/packages/permission-management